# Evitar o efeito do clique de botão sem afetar outros links

Tags: jquery

Como eu consigo no jQuery, evitar o efeito do clique de um link que tenha href="#" sem afetar o comportamento padrão de outros links.

Exemplo:

Tenho 3 links

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.meusite.com.br/">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

O que eu to tentando fazer é que quando o usuário clique no link com href = #, não tenha aquele efeito de ir pro topo da página. E ao mesmo tempo, quero que outros links da páginas funcionem normalmente. Só quero afetar o comportamento de todos os `<a href="#"></a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lugar do `#` você pode colocar:

`<a href="javascript: void(0)"> Link 2 </a>`

Ou colocar uma classe nele:

`<a href="#" class="none-link"> Link 2 </a>`

### CSS

```
a.none-link{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

`pointer-events: none` - Essa propriedade com esse valor descarta todos os eventos do elemento. Click, Hover, Focus, Etc.

Comment: Deu certinho! Obrigado!